# Why is div clearing?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with a float:left property and some width to them. They are wrapped in a container which has an overflow: hidden property.

When I change the size of my browser to be smaller in the horizontal direction I want a horizontal scroll bar to appear when the width of the window is too narrow for to display the two divs side by side. But what is happening is that the div is clearing down underneath the first div.

How can I make it so that the div does not go down when the window is too small and instead will always stay in the same row as the first div and a horizontal scroll bar will appear?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col col-1">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="col col-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my css:

```
.col-container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col {

    float: left;
}
.col-1{
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.col-2{
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3s963o9o/1/) is a fiddle with this html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the two-cols don't clear you must set a minimum-width to their container:

```
.col-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Here is your jsfiddle with the above update:
https://jsfiddle.net/3s963o9o/2/

Another option is not to use `float`, but to change the structure to flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

use `flexbox` for that instead

```css
.col-container {
  display: flex
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-1 {
  flex: 0 30%;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background: red;
}
.col-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col col-1">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col col-2">
    Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="col col-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex box ends up doing things I don't understand and floats seem to be usually simpler, and that along with less browser support (and needing more css than your solution for cross browser solutions) lead me to be cautious of flex. Maybe I just don't understand it enough. Do you disagree? Maybe I should just learn more about it

Comment: you should learn more about `flexbox`, here is a great [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: `flex: 0 30%` is the same as `flex: 0 1 30%`?